# Does Seneca Z-3AO understand a function 5 code (Modbus RTU)?

Tags: function, modbus

In the user manual they only specify address's of "Analog Output Holding Registers", which allows you to implement function codes 3, 6 and 16.

PS. I want to change a single coil (bit) in Eprflag-register (bit 12), but the user manual dose'nt specify the data address of that coil. For exemple: bit 12 has coil-number 00002, that gives us 2-1=1 as the data address.

Comment: I assume you want to force n-th bit just to evade 3/read-register + 6/write-register roundtrip?

Comment: Did you try to write a simple email to the support team of the manufacturer ? What did they reply ?

Comment: I want to avoid corrupting the rest of the Eprflag-register. Support didnt reply. But we tried all coil data addresses (0xxxx) 0000 to 270E, and found no change in modality. In addition, for example request 01050000FF008C3A gave us the respons 0185018350, an exception code, byte 3 = 1 meaning that requested function code 5 (byte 2 = function code + 0x80 = 85) is not supported. langhofer.at/fileadmin/downloads/sineaxcam/Modbus_Basics.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If the "write coils" function is not available, you may still have the possibility to read the entire register, change the desired bit, and write back the entire register.